# Build PWM controlled load for solar panel

Tags: mosfet, solar-cell, electronic-load

for my project, I need to build a variable load to measure the I-V characteristic of solar panel that I can control with a PWM signal from ESP32 (3v3).

I'm a software developer, so I do not completely understand electronic parts.

I tried to control just some MOSFET transistors, but I did not find MOSFET which I can fully open with a 3v3 signal and I got weird I-V curves. Does there exist some simple solution for that? Maybe I've just not found the correct MOSFET?

Summary:
Measure the I-V curve of 20W, 18V Solar panel, ideally from open to short circuit.
Controlled by ESP32 which can produce a 3.3V PWM.
For Voltage and current measurement, I use the INA219 module.

Comment: Something as this https://www.mouser.be/datasheet/2/308/1/NTD18N06L_D-2318500.pdf or this https://www.mouser.be/datasheet/2/308/1/NTF3055L108_D-2318842.pdf